# jQuery datatables issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

When using the [jQuery datatables plugin](http://datatables.net), why am I getting this error?

> "k is undefined" -style typeof e.saved_aaSorting=="undefined")

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I posted this answer to document something for future reference for myself, I hope it will help someone else on down the line.

From the [usage page](http://datatables.net/usage/) (a little RTFM):

> In order for DataTables to be able to function correctly, the HTML for
>   the target table must be laid out in a well formed manner with the
>   'thead' and 'tbody' sections declared.

In my case, the `<thead>` and `<tbody>` sections were missing. Oops.

Comment: Also, '<thead></thead>' has to contain some '<th></th>'

Answer (score 2):

In my case, one of the tables is without `<thead>` and `<tbody>`. It might be the cause of `"K is undefined"` error. Applying `DataTables` to the id (and not the element) could solve the problem.