# Asp.net Gridview with JQuery DataTable - Gridview events not fire

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview, jquery-plugins, datatables

In my Asp.net webb app, I have  a page having `Gridview` control binding properly with database and 
Delete/Add/Update functionality works well.

Event like  `GridView1_RowDeleting` , `GridView1_RowEditing` , `GridView1_RowUpdating` works well,

Then Later I added **JQuery DataTable**  and it looks greats, but now other events are not working.

How i can fire these Events or how i can achieve ***Edit/ Update / Delete***  functionality. 
Am new with Jquery DataTable.

Answer (score 0):

You can inline `edit/update/save/delete` your DataTable following this [example](http://www.datatables.net/blog/Inline_editing) or using the [editor](http://editor.datatables.net/)

Comment: thank your so much for usefull links , well jEditable is licience version, and i tried something with mixture of `datatable` and `inplace` and its working for me, soon i will post whole answer

Comment: @Satindersingh glad you make it. Note that the example is from datatables.net and `jEditable` is not licensed. `Editor` plugin is licensed.